# Obter os valores diferentes de uma coluna - Data Frame - Linguagem R

Tags: r

Boas malta, estou a lidar com R na faculdade a primeira vez na minha vida e estou completamente a nora!!

Então num data frame tenho uma coluna "to" que possui +20.000 valores ( iguais e diferentes ) O que eu queria saber era os valores diferentes que aparecem lá pelo menos uma vez e depois ainda saber quantas vezes aparece aquele valor.

Alguem manja de R? 
Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que o data frame se chame `x`, o comando a ser utilizado é

```
table(x$to)
```

Isto vai criar uma tabela com todos os valores únicos desta coluna e o número de vezes que cada um deles aparece.