# Contar Distinto no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de uma ajuda para construir um contagem distinta (distinct) de um data frame. Seguem os dados:

```
Filial  Matrícula   Valor
ABC      100       R$ 500,00
XYZ      200       R$ 850,00
XYZ      100       R$ 320,00
JCT      300       R$ 512,00
JCT      300       R$ 98,00
ABC      300       R$ 1.012,00
```

Gostaria que o R me desse o consolidado mostrando a contagem distinta da coluna "Matrícula" bem como a soma da coluna "Valor". Semelhante ao que a tabela dinâmica do Excel já faz. O resultado que eu desejo é:

```
Filial  Contagem/Matricula      Valor
ABC          2                R$ 1.512,00
JCT          1                R$ 610,00
XYZ          2                R$ 1.170,00
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Obter os valores diferentes de uma coluna - Data Frame - Linguagem R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168014/obter-os-valores-diferentes-de-uma-coluna-data-frame-linguagem-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o pacote `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% 
  group_by(Filial) %>% 
  summarise(Contagem = length(unique(Matrícula)), Valor = sum(Valor))
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, porém a coluna matrícula não está contando corretamente (contagem distinta), pois o resultado esperado para a coluna Filial JCT deve ser igual a 1. Ou seja, a matrícula "300" deve ser contada apena uma vez.

Comment: Porque a matrícula 300 da Filial JCT deve ser contada apenas uma vez se nos seus dados ela aparece duas?

Comment: De qualquer forma, atualizei o código que gera o resultado que você espera

Answer (score 1):

O seu exemplo de resultado parece estar errado, há *duas* linhas com `Filial` igual a `JCT`.
Além disso, para fazer contas não podemos usar objectos de classe `character`, que tenham `R$`, por isso só li os números, sem a unidade.

```
agg <- aggregate(Valor ~ Filial, dados, sum)
agg$Contagem <- tapply(dados$Matrícula, dados$Filial, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
agg <- agg[, c(1, 3, 2)]
agg
#  Filial Contagem Valor
#1    ABC        2  1512
#2    JCT        1   610
#3    XYZ        2  1170
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Filial = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ABC", 
"JCT", "XYZ"), class = "factor"), Matrícula = c(100L, 200L, 100L, 
300L, 300L, 300L), Valor = c(500, 850, 320, 512, 98, 1012)), .Names = c("Filial", 
"Matrícula", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Obrigado Rui, porém a coluna matrícula não está contando corretamente (contagem distinta), pois o resultado esperado para a coluna Filial JCT deve ser igual a 1. Ou seja, a matrícula "300" deve ser contada apena uma vez.

Comment: @BrunoAvila Veja agora, código editado. Parece que está bem.

Comment: Rui Barrada, como faria para contagem distinta com mais de uma variável? No meu exemplo, foi utilizado apenas a variável "FILIAL". Como seria utilizando "tapply" em mais de variável? Vlw

Comment: @BrunoAvila Seria `tapply(dados$Matrícula, list(var1, var2), FUN = ...)`. Mas para saber se dá certo é sempre necessário testar, é melhor editar a pergunta com um caso desses ou talvez fazer *outra* pergunta com um link para esta.

Answer (score -1):

Com dplyr:

```
library('dplyr')
dados <- dados %>% 
         group_by(Filial) %>% 
         summarise(Contagem = n_distinct(Filial),
                   Valor = sum(Valor))
```